# iOS: how to animate the fill in uibezier path?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, uibezierpath

I am working on a kids letter tracing app - see attached screen shot.

I was able to display the letter by using the bezierpath identified by the font glyphs and allow writing the touches inside the bezierpath.

Now, i want to add an help animation so that it shows how to write this letter from start to finish.

How to do that?

Consider we display "A" and i want to show animation shows how to write "A" for kids.

Any pointers / ideas.

thanks much.
[image]
[image]

Comment: updated with animation i have so far. But this is not what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I used this animation for my app. Created a circular progress bar that fills up dot clockwise

```
CABasicAnimation *pathAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath: @"path"];
pathAnim.toValue = (id)newPath.CGPath;

// -- initialize CAAnimation group with duration of 0.2secs and beginTime will begin after another.
CAAnimationGroup *anims = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
anims.animations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:pathAnim, nil];
anims.removedOnCompletion = NO;
anims.duration = 0.2f;
anims.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + anims.duration*i;
anims.fillMode  = kCAFillModeForwards;
[anims setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut]];

[progressLayer addAnimation:anims forKey:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a "built-in" way to animate the fill as you want. There is a built-in way to animate the stroke, however:

Use a `UIView` with a `CAShapeLayer` backing it. `CAShapeLayer` has a `path` property. You can then apply an animation to the layer's `strokeStart` and/or `strokeEnd` properties.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes i was able to animate the stroke, attached gif but thats not what i want. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no straightforward way to do this. I imagine the following would be easiest to implement:

1. Create a path per character that will trace how the stroke will be written. If you have limited number of characters like in the alphabet, it's possible to do this by hand. You can implement something like this to capture the path: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/smooth-freehand-drawing-on-ios--mobile-13164
2. Use your current path (in red in your photo) as a clipping mask so the fill does not overflow.
3. Stroke the path you created in 1. with a very thick stroke to do the fill.

Answer (score -1):

After loading your `bezierpath` add init the animation:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *shapeKeyframeAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
shapeKeyframeAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
shapeKeyframeAnimation.keyTimes = @[@0.0f, @0.6f, @1.0f];
shapeKeyframeAnimation.values =  @[@0.0f, @1.0f, @1.0f];
shapeKeyframeAnimation.duration = 4.0f;
shapeKeyframeAnimation.repeatCount = CGFLOAT_MAX;
```

then add it to your shape layer:

```
[shapeLayer addAnimation:_loadingKeyframeAnimation forKey:@"stoke"];
```

Comment: This animation will animate the stroke of the path. OP asked for the fill animation which is impossible to achieve using that solution. The only time this solution could solve the requested problem would be if the shape of the letter had been a simple bezier path, without the space to fill.